# 'C:\Prediction.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, system-calls

I have a test program as:

```
function [y, yy] = Prediction(x)

y = x * rand();
yy = x + rand();

end
```

Then, I complied it to `.exe` file. Now, I am using the below command to call the `Prediction.exe` into MATLAB:

```
system('C:\Prediction.exe 5')
```

Unfortunately, I am getting an error:

> 'C:\Prediction.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external
>   command,  operable program or batch file.
>
> ans =
>
> ```
>  1
> ```

I could not find a solution to resolve it. Please guide me, is that the correct way of calling an `*.exe` with inputs/outputs into MATLAB?

Comment: Are you sure `Prediction.exe` is in `C:\ ` and not in another directory?

Comment: @am304, I could sort it out, the problem was the route as you said. Now, I am using the `system('C:\Prediction.exe 5')`, but the output is `0` forever! Could u advise?

Comment: I would guess that `x` is the string `'5'`. If so, you'd need to convert it to a number first: `x=str2double(x)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the syntax

```
system('C:\Prediction.exe 5')
```

the return value is the **exit status** of the command you executed. Normally this is `0` if execution was successful and a non-zero value if not.

> `status = system(command)` calls the operating system to execute the
>   specified command. The operation waits for the command to finish
>   execution before returning the exit status of the command to the
>   status variable.

To get the output that you would see if you typed the command at the command line, you need to use a different syntax:

> `[status,cmdout] = system(command)` also
>   returns the output of the command to cmdout. This syntax is most
>   useful for commands that do not require user input, such as `dir`.
>
> `[status,cmdout] = system(command,'-echo')` also displays (echoes) the
>   command output in the MATLAB® Command Window. This syntax is most
>   useful for commands that require user input and that run correctly in
>   the MATLAB Command Window.

In order to get this output from your function I think you need to [output the values using printf](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/standalone-c-c-executables-from-matlab-code.html).

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer. I have used `[status,cmdout] = system('C:\Prediction.exe 4')` and gets the following output:

** status =
     0

cmdout =

    '42.3656
     52.9058
     '